# Flutter Http call List<t> always result Null in UI

Tags: flutter

I have try many sample in stack but still can`t get the idea which part i miss, the result in UI always display null, ..

here is the code i try :

```
class PointBallance {

  String id, date, datetime, companyid, storecode, customercode, topup, amount, remark,  cashier, invoice ;
  PointBallance({this.id, this.date, this.datetime, this.companyid, this.storecode, this.customercode, this.topup, this.amount, this.remark, this.cashier, this.invoice});

 factory PointBallance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return PointBallance(
     id: json['id'],
     date: json['date'], 
     datetime: json['datetime'], 
     companyid: json['company_id'], 
     storecode: json['store_code'], 
     customercode: json['customer_code'], 
     topup: json['topup'], 
     amount: json['amount'], 
     remark: json['remark'], 
     cashier: json['cashier'], 
     invoice: json['invoice'], 
     );
 }
}
```

the part for call http is here :

```
Future<List<PointBallance>> pointBal() async {
       var url = 'http://someUrl';
       var res = await http.get(url);
       if(res.statusCode == 200) {
         var dtpoint = json.decode(res.body);
         print(dtpoint);
         var bel = List<PointBallance>.from(dtpoint.map((i) => PointBallance.fromJson(i)));
         return bel;
       } else {
          throw Exception(
         "Request to $url failed with status ${res.statusCode}: ${res.body}"
       );
       }
    }
```

and for screen to display data ..

```
class _PointScreenState extends State<PointScreen> {
  Future<List<PointBallance>> _point;
  AuthService _authService = new AuthService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _point = _authService.pointBal();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Point'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<PointBallance>>(
          future: _point,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
               var dt = snapshot.data[0].id;
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  **Text('in the top $dt'),**
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index){
                        var hei = snapshot.data[index];
                        return **Text(hei.id != null ? hei.id : 'Cant get data')**;
                      }),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

in console i got result

```
print(dtpoint);
```

[image]

any guide to correctly display data result? because in console there is result.

Comment: you can try to change `var bel = List<PointBallance>.from(dtpoint.map((i) => PointBallance.fromJson(i)));` to `var bel = dtpoint.map((i) => PointBallance.fromJson(i));`

Comment: give the json output as text in the question. Try to use image only when you want show something in ui etc which cannot be represented in words well. Read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: You have wrong json output. Instead of `[{Balance:{id:..}},...]` try to change it `[{id:..}...]`.Or you should change your model

Comment: The output result not from my side, it comes from third party.

Comment: @Kimfdirasdfasdf is right. In `PointBallance.fromJson` you look for `id`, `date`, etc. Your root json object you pass into this function does not have these fields. instead it's like `Balance: { id: 180976, date: 2020-02-23, ... }`.

Try changing  `dtpoint.map((i) => PointBallance.fromJson(i))` to `dtpoint.map((i) => PointBallance.fromJson(i["Balance"]))`

Comment: @jnnksdev i will try this, thank for  pointing direction..